# Неточність перекладу вислову «biological dіversity», як буде вірно, біологічне різноманіття, чи біотичне?

Tags: переклад, from-english, вибір-слова

Biological dіversity — біологічне різноманіття, але ж сукупність живих органіpнім об'єднаних якоюсь ознакою це біота, а біологія це наука, проте цей термін існує серед наукового суспільства. Як все-таки правильно?
http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53393/278659.html

Comment: У чому ж неточність перекладу?«Biological» — це ж і є «біологічний». І чому це «біологічний» стосується лише науки біологія? Це слово взагалі всіх видів життя стосується. А от «біологічна зброя» – це ж не зброя із науки.)))

Comment: Мене цікавить саме словосполучення, Біологічне різноманіття чи біотичне різноманіття

Comment: Де ви чули «біотичне різноманіття»? Біота – це сукупність форм життя, що об'єднані _спільною територією_ поширення (типу тундра, тайга, савана, тощо). Коли ж ідеться про біологічне різноманіття, то мається на увазі всю нашу планету цілком, геть усі живі особиини. І ще, англійською в основному говорять не «biological dіversity», а «biodiversity», 4,8 млн. проти 55 млн. знаходжень у Гуглі, тобто «biodiversity» вживається більш ніж в 11 разів частіше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Біологічний» означає не лише «стосовний до [науки] біології», а й «стосовний до [власне] життя» ([«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/biologhichnyj), [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4508&page=169)). Тому використання вислову «біологічне різноманіття» видається прийнятним. Крім того такий термін склався історично (так уживали Генрі Бейтс у 1892, Raymond F. Dasmann у 1968, Томас Лавджой у 1980) і так часто пишуть у сучасних книжках.

<s>Щодо «біотиного»/«біотного»/«біотового», то таких прикметників я навіть не можу знайти в сучайних словниках. Тобто якщо їх уживають (разом зі словом «різноманіття» чи без) — то це явно не загальна лексика, а професійні терміни. (Конкретно «біотиний» ще, мабуть, надто асоціюється з іменником «[біотин](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191740&page=171)».)</s> Перепрошую, в початковому варіанті тексту запитання був одрук («біотиний»), тому я помилково подумав, що мова про особистий новотвір автора, а не про слово «біотичний», яке в словниках є ([«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=189290&page=171)). Термін «біотичне різноманіття» теж уживається ([результати пошуку в «Google Книгах»](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F%22&tbm=bks), [результати пошуку в «Google Scholar»](//scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F%22)) — але рідше за «біологічне різноманіття» і «біорізноманіття». А англійське «biotic diversity» зустрічається ще рідше (в порівнянні з «biological diversity» і «biodiversity») — й англійська Вікіпедія його навіть не згадує.

Ну й, звісно, є термін «біорізноманіття» ([«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191735&page=170), [Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F)).